# php copy() works on ecplise CLI environment, but does not work with web browser

Tags: php, copy

copy() function does not work in web browsers, but it works with CLI environment!!

I already checked the file permission and /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini file to check whether copy() is listed on the disable_functions. But it is not listed there :(

My os is debian by the way.
Thanks~ :)

Comment: You need to make sure that the files your moving are accessible by the user running the Apache application.  This is usually www-data:www-data, try by changing the file to 777 permissions (chmod 777 filename) and see if the copy works.  Also ensure that the directory permissions allow access as well.

Comment: oh! thanks Nigel :D it works :0 I missed giving w permissions for all the paths down to the file!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the files your moving are accessible by the user running the Apache application.

Apache usually runs as www-data:www-data, changing the file to 777 permissions (chmod 777 filename). Also ensure that the directory permissions allow access as well.

You shouldn't leave the permissions as 777 as this leaves the system open to all sorts of abuse.  There is some very good documentation and very lengthy details about this [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)